# How does python decorator work on this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to understand python decorator. I thought somehow I understood decorator until I wrote this code.

```
def func():
     def wrapper(x):
        return x()
     return wrapper 

@func()
def b():
    return sum

a = b([1,2,5])
print a # Result: 8 How?

e = b # pass b function to variable e
f = e([3,4,8]) # called function b stored in variable e
print f # Result: 15
# I understand how 15 is derived here
```

Comment: I think google gives best answer for that. https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `func` as a decorator *factory*, which produces a decorator that *called* the original `b()` to produce the decoration result. Here's what happens:

- `@func()` executes `func()` *first*, then uses the return value as the decorator. `func()` returns `wrapper`, so `wrapper` is used as the decorator.
- `wrapper(b)` sets `x = b`, and returns `x()`. So the result of the decorator is `b()`, which is `sum`. Python sets `b = sum`
- You called `b([1, 2, 5])` where `b = sum`. So `sum([1, 2, 5])` is returned.

The important part here is that you used `func` not as a decorator, but as a decorator factory (calling it produces the actual decorator), which adds a layer of indirection.